# Embedding external jQuery and CSS file to a index.php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a specific question. 
How do I embed external .js or .css file in a php file extension?

It does not work the way I embed it in html file extension.

Comment: <?php 

$var = $_POST['text'];

echo $var;
>?

Comment: This is not a proper question as there are numerous ways it can be interpreted. Please be more specific as to what your actual problem is and provide code outline

Answer (score 0):

You would usually include these inside `the <head>` tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyles.css">
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

But if you must use php for whatever reason, you can use

```
<? include "myScript.php"; ?>
```

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment about targeting outputted text, you would simply echo the text between an identifiable tag. Eg:

```
<span id:="targetThis">
    <? echo "Text" ?>
</span>
```

Now you can target the text in Css using:

```
#targetThis {
    color: red;
}
```

You can also grab it using JQuery using:

```
$('#targetThis') then do whatever it is you wanted to do with it...
```

Eg

```
$('#targetThis').html('Edited Text');
```

Comment: But if I have only a php file with only php codes in it.. and I have some echo (texts outputs to be displayed on the browser). How do I add css and jquery to it ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to show targeting for that specific echo

Comment: Why can't I use a similar technique for php like we use for html extension file?

Comment: You could just echo the whole span, like `<? echo 'span class="targetThis">Text</span>'; ?>` I just find the code easier to read when in HTML and PHP format, just personal preference